# Connect neo4j from .net using gremlin.net

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, gremlin, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gremlinnet

Am trying to connect neo4j local setup(Windows 10 WSL Ubunutu 18.04) using `Gremlin.Net` library. Neo4j server is started and its running in http://localhost:8182/. When i try to connect using below code, it throws the error `System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: 'The server returned status code '404' when status code '101' was expected.'` What am i missing here.

```
           var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182);
           var graphsonReader = new GraphSON2Reader(
                                   new Dictionary<string, IGraphSONDeserializer> { { MyType.GraphsonType, new MyTypeReader() } });
           //var graphsonWriter = new GraphSON2Writer(
           //    new Dictionary<Type, IGraphSONSerializer> { { typeof(MyType), new MyClassWriter() } });
           _connection = new GremlinClient(gremlinServer, graphsonReader, new GraphSON2Writer(), GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType);
           return _connection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you meant to type this but you wrote that "Neo4j server is started and running in....". If you specifically meant [Neo4j Server](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/#debian-installation) then [Gremlin.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gremlin.Net/) won't connect to that directly. To use that library you would need to install [Gremlin Server](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-server) and [configure Neo4j within that](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin).